# Where to ask about the easiest way to prove something?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

Some questions ask for the easiest way to prove a scientific theory. Not expertise per se, or the historical experiment that showed it first, just the easiest way. It can be very useful for pedagogy, popularization, or fighting science denial. But there seems to be no specific place to ask for this.

For instance, this user asked on the Skeptics website for [Proof that the earth is round?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/proof-that-the-earth-is-round). The question was closed as off-topic. I asked, on the Physics website, [What is the easiest way to prove that the earth is more than 10000 years old?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/301970/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-prove-that-the-earth-is-more-than-10000-years-old). It was pointed out in comments that it was not the best place to ask for this.

A well-known example of this kind of "easy proof" is the Foucault pendulum. It proves the earth rotates on itself in a very demonstrative manner, without any knowledge of mechanics or planet trajectories required from the audience. And it was found centuries after the entire scientific community knew the earth rotated on itself (it is a consequence of heliocentrism).

On which website do I ask for a Foucault pendulum? On the related science website? On Skeptics?

Comment: It might be that each website needs it's own Foucault pendulum.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to ask for proof that the earth rotates, you would probably have the most luck on [Earth Science.SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/). However, I would avoid phrasing it as asking for "*the* easiest proof;" that is often subjective. There are several ways to phrase it that, IMO, are less likely to get closed, e.g.:

- What is the easiest classroom experiment to prove...?
- What are some easy ways to prove...?
- What is the first way it was proved...?

If you wanted to ask how to prove that the earth rotates using a foucault pendulum, that might be better suited for [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

For other questions relating to "the easiest way to prove something," what site to ask on depends on what you want to prove. I would, however, avoid [Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/). If something can be easily proven, it is probably to non-controversial for there.

Answer (score 3):

Your question about Foucault pendulums is definitely not appropriate for Skeptics. Skeptics is not about skepticism itself, it's about [addressing notable claims](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/864/37236).

It's possible that Physics may accept "how to make a Foucault pendant" as a question, but I'm not a member of that site. But they may not, especially if the question shows no research...

Your quickest, easiest choices may be [Google](https://www.google.com/#q=Foucault+pendulum+diy) (for the DIY version) or [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dtoys-and-games&field-keywords=%22foucault%27s+pendulum%22&rh=n%3A165793011%2Ck%3A%22foucault%27s+pendulum%22) (for buying one outright). You should ideally do research like this before asking on any Stack Exchange site (the down vote button's hover text lists "this question does not show any research effort" on every site).

---

Note that the "proof the earth is round" question would be appropriate for Physics, except for the fact it should be closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26427), which explicitly asks for the simplest methods.

Also, it seems like your question on Physics has gained some momentum. It's not actually off-topic there, and it's even gotten some up votes.

Finally, it's worth mentioning that Skeptics already has a similar question about the age of earth: [Is the Earth 6000 years old?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1438/37236) Note that the question has a notable claim ("Dr Kent Hovind, a noted American Young Earth creationist, claims that the Earth is only 6000 years old"), which is why it's on topic.